# Create Help output in a Fortran90 program

Tags: header, fortran, output, fortran90

I've coded a scientific program in Fortran90. The source code contains a commented Help section as header in order to help the user.

However, I've seen that it is possible in C programs to code the program such as it is possible to show as standard output the header using -h as option.

Is there any way to do it in fortran?

That is, could I do something to show my header as response of "myprogram -h"?

Thanks for your help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in Fortran that will automatically spit out a section of commentary in response to a command-line flag such as `-h`.  As far as I am aware there is nothing in any current Fortran compiler which will do that for you either.

But Fortran is quite a capable programming language and, with recent intrinsics such as `get_command_argument`, you can certainly program this behaviour.

Comment: I'm currently using "iargc" and "getarg" to read the number and value of the command line arguments. I will check the use of the function you comment. Thanks.

Comment: You are currently using non-standard Fortran.  Nothing necessarily wrong with that.